# What is the mode or the command to selectively display selected region?

Tags: region, display, text, narrowing

There seems to be a command to display only the text in the selected region, leaving the rest of the text hidden. What is the command?

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to narrow and widen?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much for telling me this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Dan commented, you are referring to "narrowing" the buffer. For details read the [Narrowing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Narrowing.html#Narrowing) section in the Emacs Manual.

The command `narrow-to-region` (bound to `C-x n n` by default) will do what you want. Use `widen` (`C-x n w`) to remove the restriction and see the whole buffer again.

In some modes there may be other ways to narrow things. For example, use `narrow-to-defun` to focus on the current function in many programming modes; and in org mode you can use `org-narrow-to-subtree`.